# issue with negative lookahead in python regexp

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

The negative lookahead in my regexp is being ignored.  Is my syntax incorrect?

```
number_with_no_trailing_tag = re.compile(r"(\[number\sraw\='.+?'\])(?!\s\[)")

strings = [
    "[oper raw='+'] [number raw='9.8'] [units raw='m']",
    "foo [number raw='9.8'] bar",
    "[number raw='9.8'] bar",
    "foo [number raw='9.8']",
    "[number raw='9.8']",
    "[oper raw='+'] [number raw='9.8']",
    "[number raw='9.8'] [units raw='m']"]

matches = [number_with_no_trailing_tag.search(st) for st in strings]

for match in matches:
    if match is not None:
        print match.groups()
```

my output is:

```
("[number raw='9.8'] [units raw='m']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8'] [units raw='m']",)
```

Which is matching *all* of the strings, whereas I'm only expecting to get matches for strings[1:6]. My *expected* output would be:

```
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
("[number raw='9.8']",)
```

What gives?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you expect to get?

Comment: sorry, i posted my output, but not my *expected* output.  it's solved now though.  thanks for reminding me to edit though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `.+?` part into a negated character class ...

```
re.compile(r"(\[number\sraw='[^']+'])(?!\s\[)")
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/297121)

Comment: thanks. that fixed it.  finally I was able to achieve my ultimage goal which was:   `number_with_no_adjacent_tags = re.compile(r"(?<!\]\s)(\[number\sraw\='[^']+'\])(?!\s\[)")`

Comment: oh, and thanks for pointing me to eval.in  I've been wanting something like that forever as you can't exactly post node.js code in a jsbin, etc.